# Don't have a nullReferenceException on XML Parsing

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have wrote a c# function in order to parse an XML Stream.
My XML can have several nodes.

Example :

```
<Stream>
 <One>nnn</One>
 <Two>iii</Two>
 <Three>jjj</Three>
</Stream>
```

But sometimes, it is :

```
<Stream>
 <Two>iii</Two>
</Stream>
```

Here is my c# code :

```
var XML = from item in XElement.Parse(strXMLStream).Descendants("Stream") select item;
string strOne = string.Empty;
string strTwo = string.Empty;
string strThree =  string.Empty;

if ((item.Element("One").Value != "")
{
   strOne = item.Element("One").Value;
}

if ((item.Element("Two").Value != "")
{
   strTwo = item.Element("Two").Value;
}

if ((item.Element("Three").Value != "")
{
   strThree = item.Element("Three").Value;
}
```

With this code, if my Stream is full ( Node On, Two and three), there's no problem! But, if my Stream has only the node "Two", I get a `NullReferenceException`.

Is there a way to avoid this exception (I cannot change my Stream).

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think the answers to this question will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630192/c-sharp-check-an-element-exists-while-using-linq-to-xml. Basically you have to check if your missing `Element`s exist before trying to reference their value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if `item.Element("anything")` is `null` before accessing it's `Value` property.

```
if (item.Element("Three") != null && item.Element("Three").Value != "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
if (item.Element("One") != null)
{
   strOne = item.Element("One").Value;
}
```

`.Element(String)` returns `null` if an element of the name you requested does not exist.

Checking if value `!= ""` is pointless, because all you are preventing is the reassignment of an empty string to the `strOne` variable, which is already an empty string. Also, if you really needed to do the empty string check, using `String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)` method is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing `Value` property (which raises `NullReferenceException` if element not exist, as you already know) cast elements to strings. You can use `??` to provide default value for non-existing elements:

```
string strOne = (string)item.Element("One") ?? String.Empty;
string strTwo = (string)item.Element("Two") ?? String.Empty;
string strThree =  (string)item.Element("Three") ?? String.Empty;
```